# Show image as a node in GoJS with React

Tags: javascript, image, reactjs, gojs

im trying to show a picture as a node to be draggable for a react projet.
Im using GoJS for that. I managed to create the node and it's draggble but the image doesnt appear in it.
Here is my code :

```
    renderCanvas(){
    try{
    //1- Create a diagram (act as the view to the model/data )
    let myDiagram = 
        $(go.Diagram, "MyDiagDiv",
            {
                initialContentAlignment: go.Spot.Center,
                "undoManager.isEnabled": true
            }
        );
    // 1- End

    //4- define node template
    myDiagram.nodeTemplate = 
    $(go.Node, "Horizontal",
        {background:"#44CCFF"},
        $(go.Picture,
            {margin:10, width:50, height:50, background:"red"},
            new go.Binding("source")
        ),
        $(go.TextBlock,
            "Default Text",
            {margin:12, stroke:"white", font:"bold 16px sans-serif"},
            new go.Binding("text", "name")
        )
    );
    //4- End


    // 2- Create a model (hold the data)
    let myModel = $(go.Model);
    myModel.nodeDataArray = [
        {name: 'Alpha', source:"./Sinkv4.png"},
        {name: 'Beta', source:"./Sinkv4.png"},
        {}
    ];
    //2- End

    //3- Link diagram to model
    myDiagram.model = myModel;
    //3- End
    }catch(e){
        console.log("Error : ", e);
    }
} //End RenderCanvas
```

this is the result im getting :

[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EDCOj.jpg)

Any Idea why the pictures doesnt appear pls.
Thanks for your help

PS : the images are in the same dir as the file

Comment: can you make sure path image is correct? Is it working if you change with online sample image?

Comment: Yes it is working with and online sample image !

Comment: then you need update the path. if you use es6 you can use import image

Comment: the problem is that i have like 20 images. Should I just import them all ?

Comment: It depends on your prefer. You can map all file in json an import it or create new file js and map with import and export. Then import file and loop it. All in yours